Is a plasma force shield feasible?
I am somewhat obsessed with the plasma shields the Gungans use to protect their troops in Star Wars Episode I. They are effective against the laser cannon blasts of the Trade Federation troops but they can be easily passed through by droid troops.
I was wondering if a plasma shield like this could be possible. I did research and futurist Michio Kaku believes a high-powered plasma window could vaporize incoming objects, block radiation and particles. Also in 2015, Boeing got a patent for a plasma shield that could block the shockwave of an explosion (but not the explosion itself)
Is a plasma shield scientifically feasible for a future setting?

Another question to reference would be Properties of magnetically confined plasma shielding.

One more thing, given Clarke's third law (any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic), it's true by definition that any science-y idea is feasible in a future setting. The real question (which are the closed-as-a-duplicate reference and the second reference in the above comment) is how it can be rationalized in a world where it's not (yet) technologically feasible.

It is not possible.
I don't even need to do much science to reason this. Plasmas radiate their heat very quickly and are very hot. If you're inside a sphere of plasma, you will be in a sphere of gas instead of plasma if you do not continuously supply power to the plasma to keep it from cooling down too much. That means that you will need to put in as much heat as the plasma is radiating, meaning it will continuously radiate that much heat, meaning that you will very soon be cooked because you have pretty much just made the thing you were trying to protect the interior of a fusion reactor.
Plasma is useful for vaporizing projectiles, possibly, but you cannot have a continuous plasma shield. The best you could do is some device to "flash in" some plasma in front of incoming projectiles, but that requires being able to react to projectiles at lightning-speed arbitrarily, and if you can do that, you might as well just shoot a counter-projectile instead of going through the massive amount of work of creating a plasma generator.

What you see in Star Wars is not actual plasma. I would probably identify that as some kind of ultra-low-density fluid, responsive to EM fields as though it had metal ions dissolved into it, that has very high absorption in the spectrum of laser weapons. Then again Star Wars laser weapons are definitely not lasers, so it's probably just an ultra-low-density electromagnetically-interacting magnetorheological fluid or other non-Newtonian that turns virtually-solid upon impact.
That is actually a really cool idea in my opinion for a plasma-alike shield system: mostly see-through, manipulatable with EM devices, and passable at low speeds but impenetrable (to an extent) at high speeds. I could also imagine that on each impact, a small amount of fluid would be dissipated, and if too much dissipates, the large-scale mass of fluid ends up maintaining only a copious connection with the EM field generator that holds it in place, and it would collapse.

Wow. +1 for the plausible explanation of how SW tech could work.

plasma-alike shield system: mostly see-through, manipulatable with EM devices, and "passable at low speeds but impenetrable (to an extent) at high speeds." Isn't this the "Holtzman shield" in Dune?

@Gillgamesh Oh look, someone noticed :) It’s a more common trope than you might realize. It has very convenient properties, doesn’t it?

@controlgroup One of my favorite forcefields, right beside the Langston Field!

Plasma windows are a possibility Wikipedia page: plasma window.
However they would in effect only act as 'force screens' (not force domes) across a defined space (hence the name). So you could in theory generate a plasma shield across an doorway for example which would retain air pressure and might block some other forms of plasma or explosive residue and in theory/maybe/possibly vaporize incoming projectiles (see the Wikipedia article) Two things though;
1) To cover say a set of double doors the plasma shield would require a huge amount of electrical power which of course is not a problem in most SF scenarios: and
2) It would be scorchingly hot. So in a scenario where say you were using it as an emergency airlock (keeping air inside a spaceship) anyone trying to walk through it unprotected? Would be incinerated.
One final note there is such a thing as cold plasma's - but there is no record I can find of them being capable of being formed into effective 'windows'. There are however plenty of on-line articles on the topic as well as pictures of plasma windows in action. So perhaps you can fit them into your story.
